# Convert string column to date in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I've a dataframe where the date/time column is of string datatype and looks something like `"Tue Apr 21 01:16:19 2020"`. How do I convert this to a date column with format as `2020/04/21` in pyspark.
I tried something like this,

option1:

```
df = df.withColumn("event_time2",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("Event_time"), 'MM/dd/yyy')))
```

option2:

```
df= df.withColumn("event_time2",unix_timestamp(col("Event_time"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp"))
```

but both return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **`to_date`** and **`date_format`**. **`EEE`** is for **`day in the week`**. Refer to [Java Simple Data Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the complete list

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("Event_time2", F.to_date("Event_time", 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy')).show(truncate=False)

#+------------------------+-----------+
#|Event_time              |Event_time2|
#+------------------------+-----------+
#|Tue Apr 21 01:16:19 2020|2020-04-21 |
#+------------------------+-----------+


df.withColumn("Event_time2", F.date_format(F.to_date("Event_time", 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy'),'yyyy/MM/dd')).show(truncate=False)

#+------------------------+-----------+
#|Event_time              |Event_time2|
#+------------------------+-----------+
#|Tue Apr 21 01:16:19 2020|2020/04/21 |
#+------------------------+-----------+
```